# iterate node.js request function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, node.js

This question is about a crawler in **node.js**.
A `start_url` is given where he crawls for URLs, and "pushes" them to a .**json**-file (`output.json`).
At the moment, he runs the request function only with the `start_url`, and saves the collected URLs in `output.json`. I want that he uses the saved URLs by replacing the `start_url` with the first collected URL and collect links again ... and so on ...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var start_url = ["http://stackoverflow.com/"]

var req = function(url){
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var data = [];

        $("a").each(function() {
            var link = $(this);
                var exurls = {exurl: new Array(link.attr("href"))}

                data.push(exurls);

                // Queue "exurls" for "start_url" and call the same function with the new URL (endless loop)
                // save to "output.json" from time to time, so you can stop it anytime
        });

        fs.writeFile("output.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("File successfully written!");
            }
        });
    });
}
for (var i = 0; i < start_url.length; i++){
    req(start_url[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you want to change the code you give: it seems to be already working as you ask: it queues all found links and calls the function (`req()`) with the found URLs...

Comment: @MarcoS: Now, he runs the request function for just one time with the start_url, creates the .json-File and stops.

Comment: ... and insted you ask for ...

Comment: @MarcoS: That he also runs the request function with the found URLs, which were crawled from the `start_url` (kind of endless).

Comment: And what you want to do, with the found Urls? Save their contents, for example?

Comment: do u want it to be ever recursive function? Or you want to start with URL1, scan it for links, start with each of these links and find more links here and stop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @TaranJ, @MarcoS: Your secound idea: 1) start with the given URL (e.g. `var start_url = ["http://stackoverflow.com/"]`). 2) Now you got some URLs from the `start_url` 3) Take one URL and do the same

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs : In what conditions, you expect step1,2,3 should be stopped?

Comment: @HankChiu: During the third step because step 1 and 2 takes only a few seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you can do is make the function call recursively. The below example should work:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var start_url = ["http://stackoverflow.com/"]

var req = function(url){
  var count = 0;
  
  request(url, function(error, response, html){
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $("a").each(function() {
      var link = $(this);
      var exurls = {exurl: new Array(link.attr("href"))}

      start_url.push(exurls);

      // Queue "exurls" for "start_url" and call the same function with the new URL (endless loop)
      // save to "output.json" from time to time, so you can stop it anytime
    });

    try {
      fs.writeFileSync("output.json");
      console.log("File successfully written!");
     }catch(err){
       console.log(err);
     }
      
      ++count;
      
      if(start_url.length > count) {
        req(start_url[count]);
      }
  });
}

return req(start_url[0]);
```

The problem with this is that you are completely rewriting the file each time. If this goes on for awhile you are going to run out of memory. Another option is to create a write stream

```js
var fs = require('fs');
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');

    var start_url = ["http://stackoverflow.com/"]
    
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream("output.json");

    var req = function(url){
      
      request(url, function(error, response, html){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        $("a").each(function() {
          var link = $(this);
          var exurls = {exurl: new Array(link.attr("href"))}

          start_url.push(exurls);

          // Queue "exurls" for "start_url" and call the same function with the new URL (endless loop)
          // save to "output.json" from time to time, so you can stop it anytime
          wstream.write('"'+ exurls + '",');
        });
          
        start_url.shift();
        if(start_url.length > 0) {
          return req(start_url[0]);
        }
          
          wstream.end();
      });
    }

    req(start_url[0]);
```

Edit: switched to a basic queue so combat memory problems

---

---

Comment: Thanks. I prefer your second solution, but it displayed an error ...that I don't have enough memory ...

Comment: That is probably because you are stilling pushing to `start_url`. Variables remain completely in memory, so you are going to run out of memory pretty quickly. You need to look into creating a queue. I edited my response so that now it just keeps grabbing from the first element `start_url` and removes the first element after each iteration. This still isn't going to work after enough time because you most likely are going to be adding more than one item on each iteration. But try it out

Comment: Seems like the memory issue is fixed (at least...), but now I get a conflict with cheerio `cheerio\lib\parse.js:55`. Why not reading the output.json (meanwhile) and take everytime the next link. Thank you for your effort!